# Having trouble with SyntaxError: Unexpected Token in react native

Tags: react-native

I am currently working on a school project, and I am almost done. But there's a problem with my StyleSheet with a SyntaxError showing up as seen below in the Imgur link. It says that I need to replace a : with a }, but as you can see in the image, that shouldn't be the case. Would anyone be willing to help out? https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVPOu.png (not sure how to paste code in here without making it look all weird)
edit: link to my code on snack(I'm personally doing this on codehs) https://snack.expo.dev/L-LXxkMhf

Comment: Most likely a missed bracket above. Stack Overflow uses markdown formatting, search for "code block markdown" and you'll see the syntax.

Comment: im very new to stack overflow, where do i find code block markdown? edit: also it doesn't seem like i am missing any brackets.

Comment: Comment all the style props inside the StyleSheet and run it again. Hop, you will confirm whether the error is really inside StyleSheet or not!

Comment: i tried that but the error always moves to the next line and when i comment out my entire stylesheet it just doesn't work either. https://snack.expo.dev/L-LXxkMhf

Comment: At the very end of your stylesheet there's a bad entry that's just an asterisk. Does it fix it to take that out?